# CSS applied for the h3 tag is incorrect. Check with the requirement Specification false

Tags: html, css

[This is a demo image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AA4J.png)

The CSS Constraints to be applied are

The web page should have

[Constrainnts Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWNC1.png)

h3

The text inside h3 tag - Cascading Style Sheet

With a margin for the top as 10% , the text to be aligned to center and the font size xx-large and style “Arimo” with the color of #FFFFFF

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Capgemini</title>
 <style type="text/css">
  #home{
   border-style: solid; 
   margin-top: 15px; 
   margin-bottom: 10px; 
   margin-left: 15%;
   margin-right: 10%;
   height: 550px;
   width: 900px;
   background-color: #D9D9D9;
  }
  header{
   text-align: center;
   color: #990000;
   font-size: 25px;
  }
  p{
   text-indent:8%; 
   word-spacing: 40px; 
   color: #FFFFFF; 
   background-color: #990000;
   margin-left: 90px; 
   margin-right: 90px;
  }
  #intro{
   border-style: solid;
   margin-top: 10px; 
   margin-bottom: 10px; 
   margin-right: 15%; 
   margin-left: 15%; 
   height: 400px; 
   width: 600px; 
   background-color: #525252;
  }
  h2{
   text-align: center;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   font-size: xx-large;
  }
  h3{
   margin-top: 10%;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: xx-large;
   font-family: "Arimo";
   color: #FFFFFF;
  }
  table,tr{
   color: #FFFFFF;
   font-family: "Arimo";
   margin-top: 10px;
   margin-left: 10px;
   text-align: left;
  }
  footer{
   text-align: center; 
   color: #990000;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<section id="home">
 <header>Web Programming Learning</header>
 <p>HOME MATERIALS COMPETITION PASTYEARS ABOUT</p>
 <section id="intro">
  <h2>CAPGEMINI</h2>
  <h3>Cascading Style Sheet</h3><br>
  <table>
   <tr>
     <th>Compreshensive curriculum</th>
     <th>Insightful Guest Lectures</th> 
     <th>interaction with sponsors</th>
     <th>$30,000+in Total Prizes</th>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </section>
 <footer>
 Copyright &copy; 2017 teknoturf
 </footer>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code showing an error after evaluating as:

CSS applied for the h3 tag is incorrect. Check with the requirement Specification
false

What could be the error, though everything matches with the given constraints?

Comment: Which browser are you using? I've tried your exact code in Chrome and it opened without any error and displayed perfectly.

Comment: where are you getting this error? it shows in the browser?

Comment: Seems like this is part of an automated system huh? The validation error you are giving us comes from some script that validates your code against specifications?? What for? Is it looking at optimisations? Because if it is, it might be another reason why its bugs out.

Comment: @Salketer Yes, it is an automated system which evaluates the code against the given constraints, that's why I can't see any error in my code though it meets each and every constraint given in the table.

Comment: ... Try optimizing then... All the rules of h2 are fitted for h3 too. So make the rule apply to both, and only put the extras in the h3. Maybe that's why it cries.

Comment: @Salketer Nope, It's not working out for me.

Comment: @RajeshRiJo No not in the browser, there is a platform where we write our code and it evaluates by its own.

Answer (score 0):

Your specifications aren't clear. The top margin should be 10% of what? What your code does is give a margin of 10% of the width of the containing block. [Read W3 specifications](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/box.html#margin-properties)

It could be 10% of the height of the element, 10% of normal margin? Hard to tell.

Answer (score 0):

Your h3 tag seems correct, problem lies elsewhere. Read the description carefully and check the constraints once again. Happens with me as well!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes from "*Arimo*". It works then.

Answer (score 0):

If the error shows "CSS failed for idName is incorrect" then for this particular question try changing the text inside h2 tag as "LEARN TO LEAD" as specified in the demo image.

```
<h2>LEARN TO LEAD</h2>
     instead of 
<h2>CAPGEMINI</h2>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to run the code written below. I think this should work                or you can visit [capegemini css handson solution](http://www.youstupidcoder.com/2017/09/capegemini-css-handson.html)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <style>
 #home {
   
    border-style: solid;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    
    overflow: hidden;
    
    height: 550px;
    width: 900px;
    
    
    background-color: #D9D9D9;
   }

 #intro {
   
    border-style: solid;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-right: 15%;
    
    overflow: hidden;
    
    height: 400px;
    width: 600px;
    
    
    background-color: #525252;
    }




    header {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    color:#990000;
    }


    p
    {
      text-indent: 8%;
      word-spacing: 40px;
      color:#FFFFFF;
      background-color:#990000;
      margin-left: 90px;
      margin-right: 90px;
      }

      h2
      {
         text-align: center;
         font-size: xx-large;
         color:#FFFFFF;
        }

        h3
         {
          text-align: center;
          font-size: xx-large;
          color:#FFFFFF;
          margin-top: 10%;
          font-family: Arimo;
          }

        table
        {
        color:#FFFFFF;
        font-family: Arimo;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-left: 10px;

        }

        footer
        {
          text-align: center;
          color:#990000;

            }


        </style>
         </head>
          <body>


 

  

         <section id="home">
          <header>Web Programming Learning</header>
 
            <p>HOME
                 MATRIALS
                 COMPETITION
                 PASTYEARS
                 ABOUT

                 </p>

              <section id="intro">

               <h2>CAPGEMINI</h2>
                  <h3>Cascading Style Sheet</h3>

              <table>
             <tr><td>Comprehensive curriculum</td><td>Insightful Guest 
            Lectures</td><td>interaction with sponsors</td><td>$30,000+in Total 
            Prizes</td></tr>



           </table>

         </section>

         <footer>Copyright © 2017 teknoturf</footer>
      </section>

</body>
</html>
```